# Github Pages - trouble rendering a Page with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Whilst using Github Pages I can't get Jekyll to render a contact page. 
I am using the following template: https://github.com/antonostrovsky/tale

If I clone the template into a local repo and run `bundle exec jekyll serve` I get a page with a Contact link that I can **successfully** follow. The generated _site folder contains a subfolder 'contact' with index.html within it.

I then create an empty repository (https://github.com/antonostrovsky/test_site) at Github and specify this template in _config.yml:

```
remote_theme: antonostrovsky/tale
```

The template is successfully rendered, I can see the template on the index page (https://antonostrovsky.github.io/test_site/), and the Contact link leads to nowhere, resulting in "Not Found" error.

1. Can anyone please help me understand how I can troubleshoot this? Does Jekyll have any debug output that could be placed on a github page?
2. Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think your repo is missing a `Gemfile` according to https://github.com/antonostrovsky/tale#github-pages-method

Comment: @midzer thank you for having a look. Could you please explain what you mean? The Gemfile is present in the theme repository.

Comment: Your local development repository needs to fetch those (`Gemfile`) dependencies via `bundle`. I am not sure whether you should point to the original theme (`remote_theme: chesterhow/tale`) incase you have not modified it.

Comment: @midzer, thank you. I have opened the local repository, ensured that the Gemfile exists and ran "bundle" command. Then pushed the changes to remote repository hosting the theme. I have then pointed my website via remote_theme to my theme. And it works, apart from the Contact link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [diff between your repo and the template repo](https://github.com/chesterhow/tale/compare/master...antonostrovsky:master) and noticed that at some stage you deleted the baseurl property in the `_config.yml` file.

Forking your repo and re-adding `baseurl: "/tale"` to the `_config.yml` file fixes the contact page link for me.

UPDATE:

While the above gets the page working as a fork it doesn't work as a remote template which is what the asker needs.

The test_site has the theme and it builds, however it has no content. There are no pages in test_site repo.

If you copy your contact.md page from the theme template repo into `pages/contact.md` in the test site repo and then rebuild then your link should now work.

Note: Neither the file nor folder can start with an `_` in the test-site repo because it will get skipped over by jekyll.

Tip: Open the dev console and disable page caching then reload to see your changes on github faster. It also helps to add change some page content so that you know you're seeing the most recent version.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'll give you the bounty as you are the only person that made the effort to fork the repo and have a look. Sadly that's not quite what my issue is: I am trying to use this template repository as a jekyll template for OTHER github pages websites. So you would, for example, create a new repo with your project page and specify the repo you forked from me as the template (this is me explaining the use of remote_theme in the question). Could you please try that on your side and see if you have the same problem?

Comment: For example, I would like to use my forked/modified theme as a Jekyll template for my project: https://github.com/antonostrovsky/test_site .   I then add _config.yml as described and add the base_url variable, matching the base url of this mini-site base_url: "/test_site" . The resulting website still has faulty Contact link: https://antonostrovsky.github.io/test_site/    That is the problem :(

Comment: thank you for the update! Adding the page has solved the problem! May I ask for clarification, please? If my goal is to keep project repositories as 'clean' as possible and avoid placing the /pages/contact.md page into every single one, what would be the best way of making this contact page a part of my theme?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jekyll, so without further digging I'm not too sure. The [theme docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/) seem to suggest that themes are more for styling, layouts and shared assets. Perhaps someone else would know if you ask another question. Good luck!

Comment: Again, your help is greatly appreciated. Well done for looking into this!

Answer (score 1):

To add to the accepted answer and explain this strange behaviour. Pages from the remote theme are NOT included by design:

Custom theme files can be placed in:

```
assets/allposts.html
```

with the front matter

```
---
permalink: allposts.html
---
```

which results in the

```
 _site/allposts.html
```

file being generated.

Source: https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-remote-theme/issues/64